# read parameters passed by one jsp to another

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to read parameter passed by one `JSP` to another using `HTTP POST` method.

Following are my two `JSP` files.

*One.jsp*

```
<body>
<form action="Two.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="test value" name="txtOne">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

*Two.jsp*

```
<body>
    <% response.getWriter().println(request.getParameter("txtOne")); %>
</body>
```

I can access the parameter in *Two.jsp* file using `scriplet`.
I want to avoid `scriplet`, so I am looking for `JavaScript` or `jQuery` solution.
So far I have searched and found JavaScript solution which only reads parameters sent using `GET` method`(query string only)`.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**
I was able to get the value using JSTL:

```
${param.txtOne}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to avoid scriplet, so I am looking for JavaScript or jquery solution.

**Simply you cannot.**

request object can only accessible on server side, i.e in your JSP. You cannot access request or response object in client side that i.e `javascript/jquery/whatever.`

If you want access jsp value in javascript, try something like

```
 var news=<%= request.getParameter("txtOne")) %>;
```

As a side note: [Avoid scriplets and go for Expression language.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 1):

Try expression language - `${txtOne}`, of if the method in one.jsp is **GET** instead of **POST**, you would be able to read URL in javascript and extract parameter value from there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get the value by use of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstl)

```
${param.txtOne}
```

## Update

From [EL info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

In EL there are several [implicit objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) available.

```
EL                                  Scriptlet (out.print and null checks omitted!)
----------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------
${param.foo}                        request.getParameter("foo");
${paramValues.foo}                  request.getParameterValues("foo");
${header['user-agent']}             request.getHeader("user-agent");
${pageContext.request.contextPath}  request.getContextPath();
${cookie.somename}                  Too verbose (start with request.getCookies())
```

### Implicit Objects

The JSP expression language defines a set of implicit objects:

- pageContext: The context for the JSP page. Provides access to various objects including:
- servletContext: The context for the JSP page’s servlet and any web components contained in the same application. See Accessing the Web Context.
- session: The session object for the client. See Maintaining Client State.
- request: The request triggering the execution of the JSP page. See Getting Information from Requests.
- response: The response returned by the JSP page. See Constructing Responses.

In addition, several implicit objects are available that allow easy access to the following objects:

- param: Maps a request parameter name to a single value
- paramValues: Maps a request parameter name to an array of values
- header: Maps a request header name to a single value
- headerValues: Maps a request header name to an array of values
- cookie: Maps a cookie name to a single cookie
- initParam: Maps a context initialization parameter name to a single value

Finally, there are objects that allow access to the various scoped variables described in Using Scope Objects.

- pageScope: Maps page-scoped variable names to their values
- requestScope: Maps request-scoped variable names to their values
- sessionScope: Maps session-scoped variable names to their values
- applicationScope: Maps application-scoped variable names to their values

Answer (score 0):

It is time for you to move to some MVC framework like struts than plain JSP. Then you can fill an ActionForm from parameters and use them on Two.jsp.